# How can I convert the MainActivity code to the one from DrawerActivity (fragments)

Tags: android, charts, fragment, navigation-drawer, converters

I wrote an android application. After pressing the button, the application opens a window with files and you could select a csv file. The data from the selected file was read and plotted on the chart. I developed the app a bit and was making an app based on fragment navigation. I would like to rewrite the code to match this:

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6HSA.png)

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qzDp.png)

ChartFragment.kt

```
package com.example.aplikacjadlataty.ui.chart

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import com.example.aplikacjadlataty.R

class ChartFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var chartViewModel: ChartViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        chartViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ChartViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chart, container, false)
        return root
    }
}
```

ChartViewModel.kt

```
package com.example.aplikacjadlataty.ui.chart

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class ChartViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _text = MutableLiveData<String>().apply {
        value = "This is chart Fragment"
    }
    val text: LiveData<String> = _text
}
```

NavigationActivity.kt

```
package com.example.aplikacjadlataty

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.core.app.ShareCompat
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

class NavigationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        MobileAds.initialize(this) {}

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_chart, R.id.nav_settings
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu)
        return true
    }
    private fun onShare() {
        val shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
            .setText(getString(R.string.share_text))
            .setType("text/plain")
            .intent
        try {
            startActivity(shareIntent)
        } catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.sharing_not_available),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.shareButton -> onShare()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }


    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt(old)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
   
MobileAds.initialize(this) {}

    val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
        val lines = readCSV(uri)
        val newEntries = lines.map { line -> toEntry(line) }.groupingBy { entry -> entry.x }
            .reduce { _, accumulator, element -> if (accumulator.y > element.y) accumulator else element }.values
        val lineChart = findViewById<LineChart>(R.id.lineChart)
        val vl = LineDataSet(newEntries.toList().take(4000), "cost")
        vl.setDrawValues(false)
        vl.setDrawFilled(true)
        vl.lineWidth = 1.5f
        vl.fillColor = R.color.gray
        vl.fillAlpha = R.color.red
        vl.setDrawCircles(false)
        lineChart.data = LineData(vl)
        lineChart.notifyDataSetChanged()
        lineChart.animateX(1800, Easing.EaseInExpo)
        lineChart.description.isEnabled = false
        lineChart.isHighlightPerDragEnabled = false
        lineChart.isScaleYEnabled = false
        lineChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
    }
    findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_loadCsv)?.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        intent.type = "text/*"
        getContent.launch("text/*")
    }
    val markerView = CustomMarker(this@MainActivity, R.layout.marker_view)
    lineChart.marker = markerView
}
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun readCSV(uri: Uri?): List<String> {
    if (uri != null) {
        val csvFile = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        val isr = InputStreamReader(csvFile)
        return BufferedReader(isr).readLines()
    }
    return Collections.emptyList()
}

private fun toEntry(line: String): Entry {
    val split = line.split(";")
    val time = split[1]
    // idx 01234 012345 l:5 lub 6
    // val 84504 165959
    // 0, 3 - 845
    val secondsStartIdx = time.length - 2
    val minutesStartIdx = time.length - 4
    val hoursStartIdx = Math.max(time.length - 6, 0)

    val hour = time.substring(hoursStartIdx, hoursStartIdx + time.length - 4)
    val minutest = time.substring(minutesStartIdx, minutesStartIdx + 2)
    val seconds = time.substring(secondsStartIdx, secondsStartIdx + 2)

    val newTime =
        hour.toFloat() * 10000 + (minutest.toFloat() * 100 / 60).toInt() * 100 + (seconds.toFloat() * 100 / 60).toInt()
    return Entry(newTime, split[2].toFloat())
}
}
```

Comment: Your question is highly unclear my friend

Comment: I'd like to put the code from the old MainActivity into ChartFragment and ChartViewModel so that there are no errors

Comment: @gtxtreme look me comment

Comment: Look up how to structure MVVM or go through a tutorial from official Android docs.